# Как связать вместе usercontrol, contentcontrol и treeviewitem?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

Мне нужно написать простой прототип справки с помощью mvvm, следующим образом. Имеется treeview, где будут выбираться разделы справки. С помощью treeviewitem выбирается нужная страница справки. Каждая страница справки представляет отдельный usercontrol(в котором содержится flow document). В главном окне страницы справки отображаются в content control.

Объясните пожалуйста, как с помощью binding привязать несколько usercontrol к одному content control и чтобы, в зависимости от выбранного treeviewitem, отображался привязанный к нему  usercontrol в content control? Грубо говоря, я не могу понять как это все вместе связать с помощью binding и используя mvvm. Treeview и content control находятся на главном окне.

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так:

```
 <TreeView ItemSource="{Binding HelpIndex}" x:Name="IndexView />
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=IndexView}" />
```

т.е. В дереве отображается иерархия топиков, а в ContentControl - содержимое топика, выбранного в дереве. При необходимости можно использовать конвертер, который будет извлекать содержимое топика по его заголовку, т.е. так:

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=IndexView, Converter={StaticResource ItemContentExtractor}}" />
```

где ItemContentExtractor - лежащий в ресурсах конвертер.